# How to fix return in Wordpress template

Tags: html, css, wordpress, web

I try to program a wordpress theme but when I'm using a longer post title the text is doing this: http://prnt.sc/b3pky4

How can I fix this? In this example it looks good but when I scale it down it looks terrible. Whats the matter?

I'm using the following code:

```css
#thumbnail {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
#post {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<article id="post">

  <div id="thumbnail">

    <img width="150" height="150" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/M-Jiasmin-LeMeridien-0369-FINAL-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="M - Jiasmin LeMeridien 0369 FINAL" />
  </div>

  <h2><a href="http://localhost/2016/05/12/beitrag-6-the-last/">This is an example of a really really really long post title</a></h2>

  <div class="entry">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, … <a href="http://localhost/2016/05/12/beitrag-6-the-last/">Weiterlesen</a>
    </p>

  </div>

</article>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on how you want to fix it.  My suggestion is to truncate and use ellipses  to shorten the title:

```
h2 a {
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/

[Here's an example](https://jsfiddle.net/qjzpvgru/)

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, the image is moving right now:

Comment: I've updated my "Example" fiddle to have your HTML included.  Take a look and update that fiddle with your specific code if it's still not working.  It looks like you've removed the float on the picture, or you've put the `white-space:nowrap` on the wrong container

Comment: Thank you so much, now it works. I put the code to the wrong class